# Скрипт не работает в IE11

Tags: javascript, html

скрипт открывает поп ап окно. с настрйокам IE ковырялся, не помогает. в других браузерах работает

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn');
var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

var newModalBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn2');
var otherModalBtn = document.getElementById('other_button');
var otherModalBtn2 = document.getElementById('other_button2');
/*
А это в цикле прокруциваем те элементы которыми мы открываем модал окно
и обработчик события который открывет окно
*/
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
  myBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    openModalWindow();
  })
}
// это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow();
})

//это функция, которая открывает окно
function openModalWindow() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

newModalBtn.onclick = () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        var newModalWindow = document.createElement('div');

        

        newModalWindow.innerHTML =
            "<div id=\"for_hidden_ident\"  class=\"modal2\">" +
            "<div class=\"modal-content2\">\n" +
            "            <span class=\"newModalclose\">&times;</span>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-body\">\n" +
            "            <p id=\"modal_new_paragr\" >Ваша заявка отправлена.<br> В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с вами</p>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" 
            "</div>\n"          

        document.body.appendChild(newModalWindow);
        newModalWindow.style.display = "block";
        var newModalclose = document.getElementsByClassName('newModalclose')[0];
        
        // это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
newModalclose.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow2();
})

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow2() {
  newModalWindow.style.display =  "none";
  
}
setTimeout(() => newModalWindow.hidden = true, 2500)

    }
    
    
    
    
    otherModalBtn.onclick = () => {
        var otherModalWindow = document.createElement('div');

        

        otherModalWindow.innerHTML =
            "<div id=\"for_hidden_ident\"  class=\"modal2\">" +
            "<div class=\"modal-content2\">\n" +
            "            <span class=\"otherModalclose\">&times;</span>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-body\">\n" +
            "            <p id=\"modal_new_paragr\" >Ваша заявка отправлена.<br> В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с вами</p>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" 
            "</div>\n"          

        document.body.appendChild(otherModalWindow);
        otherModalWindow.style.display = "block";
        var otherModalclose = document.getElementsByClassName('otherModalclose')[0];
        
        // это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
otherModalclose.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow3();
})

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow3() {
  otherModalWindow.style.display =  "none";
  
}
setTimeout(() => otherModalWindow.hidden = true, 2500)

    }
    
    
    
    
        otherModalBtn2.onclick = () => {
        var otherModalWindow2 = document.createElement('div');

        

        otherModalWindow2.innerHTML =
            "<div id=\"for_hidden_ident\"  class=\"modal2\">" +
            "<div class=\"modal-content2\">\n" +
            "            <span class=\"otherModalclose2\">&times;</span>\n" +
            "        <div class=\"modal-body\">\n" +
            "            <p id=\"modal_new_paragr\" >Ваша заявка отправлена.<br> В ближайшее время мы свяжемся с вами</p>\n" +
            "        </div>\n" 
            "</div>\n"          

        document.body.appendChild(otherModalWindow2);
        otherModalWindow2.style.display = "block";
        var otherModalclose2 = document.getElementsByClassName('otherModalclose2')[0];
        
        // это обработчик события, который в нутри этой функции выполнят ту функцию 
//которая закрывает окно модальное
otherModalclose2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeModalWindow4();
})

//это функция, которая закрывает окно
function closeModalWindow4() {
  otherModalWindow2.style.display =  "none";
  
}
setTimeout(() => otherModalWindow2.hidden = true, 2500)

    }
```

Comment: IE11 не поддерживает стрелочную нотацию для анонимных функций

Comment: ( а как можно поправить?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: ооо спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Перепишите `onclick = () => { ..` в `onclick = function () {` .. как указано в коментах